# Dynamically update repository queries

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've created a query in a repository.
I want to change some elements in this query (like where condition, sort, etc) thanks to parameters sent via the function.

This function works and returns data :

```
public function dashboardIndex($offset, $limit, $order)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)         
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
    return $query;
}
```

Adding dynamic "addOrderBy" doesn't work and it doesn't return data

```
public function dashboardIndex($offset, $limit, $order)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('v');
    
    /* Sort dynamically  $order = ['column1' => 'ASC', 'column2' => DESC, ...] */
    foreach($order as $column => $direction){
        $query->addOrderBy('v.'.$column , $direction);
    }       
    /* Sort dynamically */
    
    $query->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)         
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
    return $query;
}
```

"createQueryBuilder" returns an object, but cannot it be modified all along the function?

Comment: Where do you set which entity your query builder should get the data from?

Comment: @MartinM. should be determined by the Repository it's in.

Comment: Yes, of course. Initially I didn't see anything wrong so I thought it might not be setup correctly. Now I saw that `$query` is returned, not its result. Remove `return $query;` and add a `return` to the previous line.

Comment: @MartinM. precisely ;o) did miss it at first too

Comment: "Doesn't work" sounds strange. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: You are returning the `QueryBuilder` object, not the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious statement is obvious:

*To return the result of a query, you have to return the result of the query.*

hence `return $query;` doesn't return the result, but the query.

better:

`return $query->getQuery()->getResult();`